# Cannot create snapshot in europe-west1-b

Tags: google-compute-engine

I'm trying to create a snapshot for each of my 2 persistent disks, but it never ends. The disks are both 10GB and the snapshot has been running for over 1 hour each. The disks are located in the europe-west1-b zone.

I've tried creating from both the gcutil command line tool, and from the web browser in the cloud console, and no luck with either.

I cannot delete them either as they are supposedly running??

I don't know what else I can do, any help is appreciated. Many thanks.

Comment: Hello Rob,

I have noticed the delay in creating the snapshots in europe-west1-b as well, but the issue seems to be fixed now.

Comment: Yes this problem is fixed now. I've had this confirmed by the Google Cloud team, that there was an issue in this particular zone, but it's now fixed.